# Image got Resized in Mobile View in Blogger Blog

Tags: html, css, xml, themes, blogger

I am using a template for my blogger blog (realmethemez.com) in which images are set to resize automatically in post in mobile view. In desktop view image are properly resized but in mobile view all post image get stretched. Can anyone please suggest me any code to fix that issue.

Comment: what code do you have so far? Please share a minimum viable product or share what you've tried so far

Comment: I didn't tried anything. And i don't know the exact code.

Comment: Unfortunately , we won't be able to help you with this being the case. We need something to go off of, but plain text is not enough. It's best to share a "MVP" or minimum viable product

Answer (score 0):

A little late answer but ... You do not need a code to change this! Click on an image you want to change in the editor, then options on image size will appear. Select original size. It will probably look crunchy in the editor but since that is what I understand a responsive template you have it will look perfect on the web.